# Many RegularExpression attributes in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework

I'd like to have many RegularExpression attributes for my property in EF model:

```
[RegularExpression("First regex", ErrorMessage="First error"]
[RegularExpression("Second regex", ErrorMessage="Second error"]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

But it doesn't seem to be allowed. I want to do it (or something like that), because I'd like to have different errors displayed in my form, depending on which validation didn't return true. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [create your own custom validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Comment: Not really satisfied with this approach, but it's always a solution. THX!